# Is there a fundamental flaw in operating system structure?

Tags: security, operating-system, system, computer-science

At some point I read that operating systems were meant to be created in a certain way (i.e. 'microkernel') to be resistant to fault but are made in another way (i.e. 'monolithic') for practical purposes such as speed. Whilst this is **not** the question, it does bring up the question:

**Have any fundamental tradeoffs been made in computer architecture that have reduced security from the earlier theoretical systems?**

I'm looking for answers that are accepted in the field of computer science, not opinions on current implementations. For example programs could run faster if they were all built on custom hardware, this is known, but this is impractical which is why we have general computers.

Comment: "microkernel style is the 'correct' way to make an operating system" - Linus, is that you? :-)

Comment: what exactly is the question?

Comment: @paxdiablo- Seems as if there is a fight between Linus Torvalds and the other one. ha ha ha. SIR,you've really made my day today with 2 such posts.

Comment: There is a "proper theoretical way to do things" that prevents security holes: formal verification.  However, formal verification is exceptionally expensive.  The first formally verified kernel was from 2009, which is very recent, considering that formal verification is an old concept.

Comment: Your question is not on-topic for StackOverflow (specific programming problems or related questions) but it looks like it is on-topic for the Computer Science stackexchange site https://cs.stackexchange.com/ (tag `operating-systems`)

Comment: ok, how do I go about moving it without losing the answers?

Comment: @user2353082- If any of the answers does help, please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted! https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @DietrichEpp formal verification is so limited, though. You can only formally verify certain things, you can't verify "security" but you can verify "no buffer overflows". And it's so damn expensive that I don't know anyone who considers it practical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone saying that microkernels are "the right way" is wrong. There is no "right way". There is no objectively best approach to security.

The problem is that security is not fundamental to computing. It's a sociological issue in a lot of ways, it only exists because humans exist - unlike computation, which is a literal science.

That said, there are principals of security that have held true and been incorporated into hardware and software, like the principal of least privilege. The kernel in an operating systems, on the hardware, runs at a higher privilege level than userland processes. That's why your program can't actually interact with hardware, and has to use system calls to do so.

There are also issues of complexity, and various measurements of complexity. Programs tend to get more complex as our needs grow - instead of a basic game of pong we now have 1,000 AI units on a giant map. Complexity goes up, and our ability to reason about the program will likely go down, opening up holes for vulnerabilities.

There's no real answer to your question but this - if there is an objective method for security we haven't discovered it yet.

Answer (score 0):

> SECURITY IS NOT A FUNCTION OF NATURE OF KERNEL.

Types of kernels has nothing to do with the security of the operating system. Though I would agree that the efficiecny of an operating system does depend on it's nature.

Monolithic kernel is a single large processes running entirely in a single address space. It is a single static binary file. Whereas, in Microkernels, the kernel is broken down into separate processes, known as servers. Some of the servers run in kernel space and some run in user-space. All servers are kept separate and run in different address spaces.The communication in microkernels is done via message passing.

Developers seem to prefer micro-kernels where as it provides flexibility and also it is more easy to work with different userspaces. Monolithic is somewhat complex in it's nature and is beneficial for lightweight systems.

> Is their some fundamentally flawed way our computers are structured
>   that allow all the security holes that are found? What I mean by this,
>   is that there are sometimes the proper theoretical ways to do things
>   in computer science that satisfy all our requirements and are robust,
>   etc, .

Their are certain concepts like [protection-ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protection_ring) and [capability based security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capability-based_security) and all,but, at the end this depends on the requirements of the system. For more clarity be sure to visit the links provided. SOmewhat minor ideas are highlighted below.

**Capability-based_security :-** Although most operating systems implement a facility which resembles capabilities, they typically do not provide enough support to allow for the exchange of capabilities among possibly mutually untrusting entities to be the primary means of granting and distributing access rights throughout the system.

**Protection_ring :-** Computer operating systems provide different levels of access to resources. A protection ring is one of two or more hierarchical levels or layers of privilege within the architecture of a computer system. This is generally hardware-enforced by some CPU architectures that provide different CPU modes at the hardware or microcode level. Rings are arranged in a hierarchy from most privileged (most trusted, usually numbered zero) to least privileged (least trusted, usually with the highest ring number).